# Only display modal one time in Asp.Net Core 3 web app

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, asp.net-core-3.0

I updated one of the websites I work on and we have a welcome modal on the home page. I only want that modal to show up for 60 days, and only the first time someone surfs to that page. (obviously, it currently displays ever time you move to that page)

I can add a claim once the user logs in to control that but how does one do that for an unregistered, basic user?

The modal is loading via the window onload javascript event. I assume the date checking should be done there?

```
<script>

    $(window).on('load',function(){

        $('#modal-welcome').modal('show');

    });
    //make sure modal is in center of screen
    function alignModal() {
        var modalDialog = $(this).find(".modal-dialog");
        /* Applying the top margin on modal dialog to align it vertically center */
        modalDialog.css("margin-top", Math.max(0, ($(window).height() - modalDialog.height()) / 2));
    }
    // Align modal when it is displayed
    $(".modal").on("shown.bs.modal", alignModal);

    // Align modal when user resize the window
    $(window).on("resize", function () {
        $(".modal:visible").each(alignModal);
    });

</script>
```

Here is the modal

```
<!-- Welcome Modal -->
<div id="modal-welcome" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-popout">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="block block-themed block-transparent remove-margin-b">
                <div class="block-header bg-primary-dark">
                    <ul class="block-options">
                        <li>
                          <button data-dismiss="modal" type="button"><i class="si si-close"></i></button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <h3 class="block-title text-center">Welcome to our updated website!</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="block-content">
                    <partial name="_WelcomePartial" />                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button id="modal-welcome-agree" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Surf Away!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END Terms Modal -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thru a bit of searching with different terms. There is now sessionStorage which lasts the whole browsing session in HTML 5. This is the way to go. The script is simple.

```
 <script>
    var today = new Date();
    //put whatever future date you want below
    var showUntil = new Date("2019-12-31");

    if (sessionStorage.getItem("shown") === null) {
        //show only until the end of the year
        if (today < showUntil) {
            $(window).on('load',function(){
                $('#modal-welcome').modal('show');
                sessionStorage.setItem("shown","true");
            });
        }
    }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to find any modals on the page and put an "if not visible" around each event makes one appear, something like this:

```
// assuming "modal" is a class that exists on every modal
if (!$(".modal").is(":visible")) {
  // event that makes a modal appear goes here
}
```

So the logic goes, if there isn't a modal already visible, make this one visible.